# Does NSMutableArray shift its elements if you delete the first element?

Tags: cocoa, nsarray

Does `NSArray` shift its elements down if you delete the first element (similar to how an ArrayList works in Java) or not (similar to an array in java)?

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: Could you please edit the question title to specify NSMutableArray instead of NSArray. I feel that will avoid confusions. Because you can't delete an item from a NSArray. You can do that only with NSMutableArray.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it is documented in the `NSMutableArray`* class for [`removeObjectAtIndex:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableArray/removeObjectAtIndex:).

> **Discussion**
>   To fill the gap, all elements beyond index are moved by
>   subtracting 1 from their index.

<sub>*Remember you can only remove objects from a mutable array.</sub>

Answer (score 3):

This would be quite easy to try out, but yes it does. Note that you can't remove objects from an NSArray however, only from an NSMutableArray.

Answer (score 0):

NSArray contain of static objects you can do this operations in NSMutableArray. And Yes it does.